# How to INNER JOIN multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables that look like so:

```
dog
ID
<numerous fields>
vetID

client
ID
<again, numerous fields I don't think are relevant>

vet
ID
<More irrelevant fields>

dogclient
ID
DogID
ClientID
```

I'm trying to get all the information from all these tables for a specific dog's ID. I tried this query in a PDO prepared statement

```
SELECT dog.*, client.*, vet.* 
FROM dogclient 
INNER JOIN client ON dogClient.ClientID = client.ID 
INNER JOIN dog ON dogclient.DogID = dog.ID 
INNER JOIN dog.vetID = vet.ID 
WHERE dogclient.dogID = :id
```

the result was a syntax error in the query at:

```
'.ID WHERE dogclient.dogID = '4''
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ah, I see, you didn't join to vet. `INNER JOIN vet ON dog.vetID = vet.ID`

Comment: Simple: use in the third join (where the error message points to) the same syntax than in the two previous ones.

Comment: ID in the dog client table appears to serve no purpose - just sayin'

Comment: I was taught in uni to give everything a unique ID, this way, should i need it in the future, I have it already... I also think i might need it when i start giving the website i'm making the ability to change and delete things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT dog.*, client.*, vet.* FROM dogclient 
    INNER JOIN client ON dogClient.ClientID = client.ID 
    INNER JOIN dog ON dogclient.DogID = dog.ID 
    INNER JOIN vet ON dog.vetID = vet.ID 
    WHERE dogclient.dogID = :id
```

you were missing the vet table in the last inner join

Comment: I didn't expect that result... vet.Name, replaced dog.Name in the result... is there a way in SQL to stop that from happening? (there's a few fields that have been replaced because 2 tables have the same field names)

Comment: I don't think that should be happening.  The simplest way to ensure it doesn't is calling them out specifically

Comment: That's what i ended up doing, thanks for the help :)